# How to call the controller task on each 1 min interval

Tags: plugins, joomla, controller, task, joomla3.0

I have created task on controller and there is loop which is loading for 100 times.
Now I want to load it for 25 times and pause that loop for 1 min and after that it will execute next 25 items same for next 25.
I have checked it with sleep but its not working.
Can you please advise me if is there any way on plugin event or any other method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually unrelated to Joomla! Since you're creating a long running process you need to start it with something else than a browser. A CRON job is a good idea here if you want to execute this operation multiple times. Otherwise it can run via command line. Make sure the max_execution time setting of PHP does not cause any trouble.

If you still need this within Joomla please have a look at the CLI documentation.

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_stand-alone_application_using_the_Joomla!_Platform